# How to insert an iframe (a youtube video) inside a JEditorPane?

Tags: java, iframe, jeditorpane

I have created a JEditorPane and am able to work with other HTML tags other than iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch this side: [Youtube iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=de)

and this: [HTML in Swing Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)

I hope this will help you.